# How to execute jar file on double click

Tags: java, jdk, doubleclick

BACKGROUND: I went to oracle.com and I downloaded the JDK. I moved the file to /usr/local/java. Afterwards, I set the path variable and JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment.

PROBLEM: I have a jar file in my downloads directory. Although I can go to terminal and use "java -jar" and it works, I want to be able to double click and execute the jar file.

Comment: Sorry if the question sounds stupid and is obvious, I just installed ubuntu yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click on `.jar` file
- Select "Properties" tab
- Select your Java Runtime
- Press <kbd>Set as default</kbd>

[image]

Now you can open/execute any `.jar` file by double clicking them

**UPDATE**

If you cannot find "OpenJDK" option, maybe you don’t have the runtime environment installed. Use below command to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Comment: It doesn't show up in the "open with"

Comment: @PrinceRajaruban See my edit